# Why do we use typedef in structure when we have a shorter method

Tags: c++, struct

When I define some random structure like for example in a cpp file in Visual studio

```
1)    struct CAddition {
    int x, y;

    CAddition(int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }
    int result() { return x + y; }
};
```

and now if I define some structure object

```
CAddition foo;
```

it works without any error 
but if I use any alias in the end

```
2) struct CAddition {

    int x, y;

CAddition(int a, int b) { x = a; y = b; }
int result() { return x + y; }
}CAddition;
```

I cannot simply define any object without using struct before the definition

```
 struct CAddition foo;
```

or an alternative method would be to add

```
typedef struct CAddition {
```

In the method 2 to avoid rewriting struct every time , My question is whats the difference between these 2 definitions , doesn't method 1 use less keywords and much easier to use in what conditions should we use the second definition of a structure.

Comment: In 2) you declare a variable named `CAddition` of the type `CAddition` you just created, thus you hide the type, and you need `struct` to tell the compiler you want the type and not the object, though I don't know if this is actually allowed by the standard...

Comment: `struct CAddition { /*..*/}CAddition;` defines both a type and an instance (with same name), it is not an alias.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 'struct' and 'typedef struct' in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c)

Comment: Think of it this way: a `struct` definition in C++ is merely a `class` with public members only, unless specified otherwise. It doesn't behave differently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `struct CAddition { ... } CAddition;` you are doing two things:

1. You define the structure `CAddition` as a typename. That's what the `struct CAddition` thing does.
2. You define the ***variable*** `CAddition`. The variable is the one *after* the structure.

Because you define the variable `CAddition` you can not use that name for the type, as then the compiler will think you mean the variable and not the structure. To solve this you need to use `struct CAddition` to explicitly tell the compiler you mean the structure typename.

---

On an unrelated note: A `struct` is just like a `class`, with the difference being that all members a `public` by default in a `struct`. So you don't need the `public` specification in a `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

> it works without any error but if I use any alias in the end

In 2) you are not using an "alias", but you create an instance of that class you just defined (structs and classes are the same in c++ btw). You then have an instance with a name that shadows the class name and as a consequence you need the `struct CAddtion` to tell the compiler that `CAddition` refers to the class not to the instance you created.